# How do you actually make use of joined tables once they exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My database stores a list of people, and what pets they own.

```
rails generate model Pet name:string species:string
rails generate model Owner name:string
```

### app/models/owner.rb

```
has_many :pets
```

### app/models/pet.rb

```
belongs_to :owner
```

Then I run `rake db:migrate`, and enter the Rails console to try it out.

```
Owner.create name: "Sarah"
Owner.create name: "David
santos = Pet.new name: "Santos L Halper", species: "Dog"
```

Now I want to tell Rails exactly who owns Santos. How do I actually do this, how do I express a relationship across the join?

I thought it might be `santos.owner = Owner.find(1)`, but no. My books don't actually address this question, they seem to just kind of assume that the relationships exist magically. I'm really frustrated because I've spent all evening on this and have gotten nowhere, and can't find the information anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What is missing for you is to create a foreign key, through a rails migration, in your `Pet` model. If you follow the convention, the column in the database should be called `owner_id`
Once you have run the migration, the code you wrote in the question should work.

Regarding where to find information: The rails guides are pretty useful.

Here is the one covering the associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

For your particular has_many case: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Other guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you didn't forget to put `owner_id` into `pets` table.
then, you can do it like this:

```
owner = Owner.find(1) // find some owner
pet = owner.pets.create(name: 'Santos', species: 'Dog')
```

and that owner is related to your new Pet. You can use `build` instead of `create` method, but in that case you have to save it manually. This example saves the pet automatically in database.

**UPDATE:**

now, if you want to see all pets of owner, you will use:

```
owner = Owner.find(1) // find some owner
pets = owner.pets
```

or if you have some pet, you can find owner:

```
pet = Pet.find(1) // find some pet
owner = pet.owner
```